# How to set schema.registry.URL?

Tags: serialization, f#, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I'm testing sending GenericRecord. But the following code

```
let fullName = "Test k"
let uniEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding()
let str = uniEncoding.GetBytes("abcdefg")

use ms = new MemoryStream()
ms.Write(str, 0, str.Length)
let content = ms.ToArray()

let config = new Dictionary<string, Object>()
config.Add("bootstrap.servers", "10.0.0.2:9092")
config.Add("schema.registry.url", "http://bing.com")
let s = Schema.Parse(
            """{
                "namespace": "nnnnnnnn",
                "type": "record",
                "name": "fffffnnnnnn",
                "fields": [
                    {"name": "file_name", "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "time",  "type": "string"},
                    {"name": "content", "type": "bytes"}
                ]
                }""") :?> RecordSchema
use producer = new Producer<string, GenericRecord>(
                 config, new AvroSerializer<string>(), new AvroSerializer<GenericRecord>())
let record = new GenericRecord(s)
record.Add("file_name", fullName)
record.Add("time", DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString())
record.Add("content", content)
let dr = producer.ProduceAsync("Topic1", fullName, record).Result // error

0 // return an integer exit code
```

returns this error

> HttpRequestException: [http://bing.com/] ServiceUnavailable[http://bing.com/] ServiceUnavailable -1

What value should I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `bing.com` is **not** a Schema Registry

You need to download Confluent OSS Distribution and configure and run (assuming Linux, but `bin\windows\` works otherwise)

```
<confluent_home>/bin/schema-registry-start <confluent_home>/etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

Then you would use something like `http://schema-registry.server.name:8081/`

Refer to [documentation for more information](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/docs/index.html)

Comment: Is there a way which doesn't need the Confluent OSS distributrion since I'm using the `GenericRecord`?

Comment: Confluent Platform has nothing to do with the Avro data types you use... Your code still requires you run a server that's capable of accepting requests containing Avro schemas

Comment: I was using Kafka sending strings and it doesn't require the Confluent platform. Is it required when using avro only?

Comment: Confluent's Kafka installation still supports strings, it's not a different Kafka version. So no, it's just required to use the Schema Registry, which happens to give you Avro Serializer support. For complete information, see https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/README.md